What will be the limit definition of partial derivative at point $(0, 0)$?
Let there be $f(x, y)$ = $\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ if $(x, y)$ is not equal to the origin and $f(0, 0) = 0$.
My goal was to get the partial derivative and mixed derivatives of $f(x, y)$.
It was easy to get both $f_x$ = $\frac{y^3 - (x^2)y}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}$ and $f_y$= $\frac{x^3 - (y^2)x} {(x^2 + y^2)^2}$. (Sorry I couldn't write them in proper form)
However, for me, it was hard to get to determine if there was a partial derivative for point $(0, 0)$ for both $f_x$ and $f_y$.
Can anyone explain how to do it using the limit definition for derivatives?
Also, using the same method, please let me know how to evaluate the mixed derivatives, which are $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ of the point $(0, 0)$ as well.

You need to use $ signs for mathematics mode. Have you seen the MathJax tutorial?

Thanks, I  did, but I was on a car so I couldn't write all those down. Thank you for editing though.

$f$ is not even continuous in $(0,0)$ (e.g. $f(x,x)=\frac 12\neq 0$). I doubt you can even give some sense to partial derivatives in that point...

@zwim  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative This article says the function need not be continuous. I am confused now too.

By definition,
$\begin{align}
f_x&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}h\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\tfrac{(x+h)y}{(x+h)^2+y^2}-\tfrac{xy}{x^2+y^2}}h\\
&=y\lim_{h\to0}\large\tfrac{(x+h)(x^2+y^2)-x[(x+h)^2+y^2]}{h(x^2+y^2)[(x+h)^2+y^2])}\\
&=y\lim_{h\to0}
\large\tfrac{hy^2-hx^2-h^2x}{h(x^2+y^2)[(x+h)^2+y^2])}\\
&=y\frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
\end{align}
$
Similarly, we can find $f_y$. Higher order partial derivatives are found recursively, but they are much more complicated. For example, $f_{xx}=(f_x)_x$. Notice that binomial expansion in the numerator is the key when evaluating the limit.
For evaluating $f_x(0,0)$, you said there is a confusion. But, we do the same. By definition,
$$\begin{align}
f_x(0,0)&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}h\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h,0)-0}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{0-0}{h}\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$
Similarly, $f_y(0,0)=0.$
For higher order derivatives. We do it recursively.
For example, $f_{xx}(0,0)=(f_x)_x(0,0)=0$, knowing $f_x(h,0)=0$ and $f_x(0,0)=0.$
Another example,
$$\begin{align}
f_{xy}(0,0)&=(f_x)_y(0,0)\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f_x(0,0+h)-f_x(0,0)}h\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f_x(0,h)-0}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\tfrac1h-0}{h}\\
&=DNE
\end{align}
$$

I have a question in the last part in fxy(0,0). Isn’t the limit of 1/(h^2)when h goes to 0 is infinity? Could you explain why is it DNE?

@FORZAINTER Infinity is not a real number, plus or minus does not matter. For these, they sometimes write DNE in calculus. But, i agree, $\infty$ is better.

@BobDoss Thank you!

Just check the definition. $f_x(0,0)=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x} =0$, $f_y(0,0)=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{f(0,y)-f(0,0)}{y}=0$.
For $f_{xy}$, first compute $f_x(0,y)$ and then $f_{xy}(0,0)=\lim\limits_{y\to 0} \frac{f_x(0,y)-f_x(0,0)}{y}$. Similar for $f_{yx}$.

In second derivative $y\to0$?

@BobDobbs Thank you, I have edited it.
